# Is there anyway to export feols model using stargazer in R?

Tags: r, export, stargazer, fixest

I ran a bunch of models using `feols` model (`fixest` package), but I have trouble exporting my model into a table using `stargazer`. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

It does seem like I can use `etable` function, but I want to use `stargazer` because I want to add a couple lines of notes to my table and format the table the way I want it (e.g. using `table.layout` function in `stargazer`).

Comment: I do not believe that `stargazer` supports this kind of model. However, it is supported out-of-the-box by the [`modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/). This package allows you to add notes and tables are infinitely customizable. Of course, this is a different package, which is why I write this as a comment instead of an answer. (Disclaimer: I am the author)

Comment: @Vincent This should be an answer

Comment: @Jakob I wasn't sure because the author explicitly states that they want to use one specific argument of the `stargazer` package. FWIW, there's a `fixest` example on the website: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#fixest-fixed-effects-and-instrumental-variable-regression

Comment: @Vincent I get that but if you google how to make fixest latex tables, you arrive here. And if you're in a rush you won't look into the comments.

Comment: @Jakob Good point. I added an answer.

Answer (score 9):

I do not believe that stargazer supports this kind of model. However, [it is supported out-of-the-box by the modelsummary package.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/) This package allows you to add notes, and the tables it produces are extremely customizable, because `modelsummary` supports several backend packages to create and customize tables: `kableExtra`, `gt`, `flextable`, `huxtable`.  Tables can also be exported to *many* formats, including HTML, Markdown, LaTeX, JPG, data.frame, or PDF.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of `modelsummary`.)

Here is an example with a simple linear regression model:

```
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

# create a toy dataset
base <- iris
names(base) <- c("y", "x1", "x_endo_1", "x_inst_1", "fe")
base$x_inst_2 <- 0.2 * base$y + 0.2 * base$x_endo_1 + rnorm(150, sd = 0.5)
base$x_endo_2 <- 0.2 * base$y - 0.2 * base$x_inst_1 + rnorm(150, sd = 0.5)

# estimate
mod <- feols(y ~ sw(x1, x_endo_1, x_inst_1) | fe, data = base)

# table
modelsummary(mod)
```

[image]

You can use the various formula functions that `fixest` offers like step-wise inclusion of covariates:

```
mod <- feols(y ~ sw(x1, x_endo_1, x_inst_1) | fe, data = base)
modelsummary(mod)
```

[image]

And `modelsummary` also supports instrumental variable estimation. This will show both stages side-by-side:

```
mod <- feols(y ~ x1 | fe | x_endo_1 + x_endo_2 ~ x_inst_1 + x_inst_2, data = base)
modelsummary(summary(mod, stage = 1:2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may also use the `etable` function from **fixest** to export output tables:

```
library(fixest)
data("mtcars")

# models
model1 <- feols(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data=mtcars)
model2 <- feols(mpg ~ cyl +  hp, data=mtcars)

# data.frame output
df <- etable(list(model1, model2), tex=FALSE)

# Latex output
etable(list(model1, model2), tex=TRUE)
```

You can also save the output locally with the `file` parameter.

`etable(list(model1, model2), tex=FALSE, file ='tt.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

As of `fixest` 0.10.2, [table notes](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/etable_new_features.html#support-for-threeparttable-notes) are now supported in `etable`.